# if today add class selected

Tags: javascript, php

I have som problems with javascript code and i have my solution in php but i need it in javascript, can anyone give me some tips how to translate it ?

```
      <select>
  <?php
  $current_month = date("n"); 
  ?>
  <option value='1' <?php if($current_month == 1) { echo "selected";} ?>>January</option>
  <option value='2' <?php if($current_month == 2) { echo "selected";} ?>>February</option>
  <option value='3' <?php if($current_month == 3) { echo "selected";} ?>>Mars</option>
  <option value='4' <?php if($current_month == 4) { echo "selected";} ?>>April</option>
  <option value='5' <?php if($current_month == 5) { echo "selected";} ?>>May</option>
  <option value='6' <?php if($current_month == 6) { echo "selected";} ?>>June</option>
  <option value='7' <?php if($current_month == 7) { echo "selected";} ?>>July</option>
  <option value='8' <?php if($current_month == 8) { echo "selected";} ?>>August</option>
  <option value='9' <?php if($current_month == 9) { echo "selected";} ?>>September</option>
  <option value='10' <?php if($current_month == 10) { echo "selected";} ?>>October</option>
  <option value='11' <?php if($current_month == 11) { echo "selected";} ?>>November</option>
  <option value='12' <?php if($current_month == 12) { echo "selected";} ?>>December</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Take a look at `Date::getMonth()`.

Comment: No, we cannot translate it for you. SO is not a code writing service. You need to write the code yourself - and then, if you encounter issues, come back and we'll try to help you with them.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Okey i take a look at the getMonth()

Comment: Sorry @AleksG my bad i will edit my tread for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the value of the select element to change the selected option with Javascript. (Note that you'll have to give it an id for my example to work.)

```
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

document.getElementById('months').value = currentMonth;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R8gms/